# QoS for Firebird database connections - how?

Tags: firebird, qos

Our Firebird database connection goes through a network connection that seems to imply a high latency for normal TCP connections. However, I am quite sure that the network connection supports quality-of-service on network traffic. Is there any way to specify QoS parameters to a Firebird connection?

Comment: From my point of view, this question does not belong to StackOverflow, but to ServerFault.

Comment: I would prefer to see a gds32.dll api call or OS api call as a solution, that is why it is on stackoverflow.com, too - but I don't consider this likely. I think that a tcp tunnel solution or server configuration solution is most likely to be found first.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is going to be dependent on the configuration capabilities of your network hardware.

One thought, if the server hosting the database is primarily just for hosting the database, or the other services on it are also important, see if you can configure traffic to/from that server to a higher priority than standard traffic.

Answer (score -1):

May be you can try to use compressed “tunnel” for TCP/IP like [Zebedee](http://www.firebirdsql.org/downloads/firebird_zebedee_eng.pdf)

Comment: Compressing is not the issue here.